# Probability that students from same school are in the same room

Tags: probability

> Let there are $8$ students, $2$ from each of $4$ different schools. They have to be placed in $4$ rooms with $2$ students in each room. What is the probability that students of the same school are in the same room?

My attempt:

The total number of ways in which $8$ students can be assigned in $4$ rooms with groups of $2$ is  $$T={8\choose2}4+{6\choose2}3+{4\choose2}2+{2\choose2}1$$
(At first I select two out of the 8 students and place them in one of the 4 rooms then I select 2 from the remaining 6 and place them in the remaining 3 and so on ).

Also, total number of ways in which $4$ groups of $2$ students in each group (students of each school) can be arranged in $4$ rooms is $4!$.

So, $$P=\frac{4!}{T}$$

But this is wrong. Can someone point out why?

Comment: This looks like a problem collected from or inspired by some source. According to discussions in Meta, we aim to include sources for all applicable questions. Please [edit] your question to include the source. Refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29290/is-it-a-good-idea-to-include-source-from-where-a-question-is-taken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcounting because you're multiplying to choose the rooms at each step; instead, the procedure you describe should be "pick the two students for room $1$, pick the students for room $2$, and so on." You'll note that there are multiple ways for you to get the same arrangement here. For example, if the first two students you choose are from school $A$ and put in room $2$, then you would also count this when you count cases where the second two students you choose are from school $A$ and get put in room $2$ (assume all the other assignments are the same). Additionally, you need to multiply when performing multiple steps in order. It should be that $T = \binom{8}{2} \binom{6}{2} \binom{4}{2} \binom{2}{2}$.

Comment: I didn't understand why I am overcounting

Comment: Consider an example with two schools. $A$ has students $a_1,a_2$ and $B$ has students $b_1,b_2$ and the classrooms are $1,2$. Your procedure first picks a classroom, then two students; then the other classroom and its students. So picking $a_1,a_2$ to go into classroom $1$ and $b_1,b_2$ to go into classroom $2$ is the same as picking $b_1,b_2$ to go into classroom $2$ and $a_1,a_2$ to go into classroom $1$. Your method counts both of these.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but an alternative route.

Place a student in one of the rooms.

Now select one of $7$ remaining spots for his schoolmate.

Exactly one of the spots brings the schoolmates in the same room.

Probability on that : $\frac17$.

Then under condition that this happens repeat it with the remaining  $6$ students and $3$ rooms.

Repeat again and you will end up with probability :$$\frac17\frac15\frac13$$